# Google Maps Default.css stylesheet import

Tags: javascript, django, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I'm trying to set up a simple style google map on my website. I have literally copied the basic map into my HTML and it worked, but when I do the same with the Simple Styled Map, it fails. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-styled-simple

The error is [from a django mysql server]

```
[22/Jul/2013 10:05:24] "GET /maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2160
```

the part of the html that is calling this is in the header

```
 <link href="/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Now my question is:

What is this supposed to be in the default.css?

Do I need to use this specific stylesheet or can I use the one from the rest of my site?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a specific stylesheet, but you must set at least a height for the `#map-canvas`.

In the failing example the height is set via the external stylesheet, that's why you don't see anything, because the stylesheet can't be loaded .

Comment: Thanks, This led to the solution. The exact solution was to add "html, body, #map-canvas {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
      }"